# iAd in iBooks - is this possible?

Tags: iad, ibooks

Looking at including iAds within an iBook. Is this at all possible as I don't seem to be able to find reference to this option anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, you can not have Ads in iBooks. The only way to make money in iBooks is to sell the your book.